# Rendering component before fetching data has been finished

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, state

I'm trying to fetch data by creating a function. In that function I am doing trying to set state and I am calling it from the `componentDidMount` method, but I am having a few problems:

1. I am not sure if `while` is good practice to be used, because I am looping and changing my endpoint so I can get new data every time.
2. I have tried to return data from the fetching function and use `setState` inside `componentDidMount`, but I had a problem, I suspect because `componentDidMount` is running before fetching has completed
3. I have tried to use `res.json()` on the data using a promise, but I got an error that `res.json` is not a function.

```js
state = {
    title: [],
    image: [],
    rating: [],
  };

getData =  () => {
    let i = 1;
    while (i <= 9) {
       axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${i}`)
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .then(response => this.setState({
        title:response.data.data.name[i],
      }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
      i++;
    }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    console.log(this.state.title);
  }
```

Comment: You probably don't want to setState 10 time s in the loop.  Do you have to make 10 API calls?  If so I'd save a local array variable in the loop and setState after the loop.  If you can get all the necessary data in one call, that would probably be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to render your `JSX` after you're done fetching information, then I'd suggest creating an additional item in your `state`, `isLoading`, that you can set to `true` or `false` and render your `JSX` conditionally.

Based on the example you provided below, it'd look like the following:

```js
class Shows extends React.Component {
  state = { 
    title: [], 
    image: [],
    rating: [],
    isLoading: true
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData()
  }

  getData = () => {
    // I've created a URL for each request
    const requestUrls = Array.from({ length: 9 })
      .map((_, idx) => `http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${idx + 1}`);

    const handleResponse = (data) => {
      // `data` is an array of all shows that you've requested

      // extract information about each show from the payload
      const shows = data.map(show => show.data)

      // handle shows data however you need it
      // and don't forget to set `isLoading` state to `false`
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        title: shows.map(show => show.name),
        image: shows.map(show => show.url),
        rating: shows.map(show => show.rating.average),
      })
    }
    const handleError = (error) => {
      // handle errors appropriately
      // and don't forget to set `isLoading` to `false`
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false
      })
    }

    // use `Promise.all()` to trigger all API requests
    // and resolve when all requests are completed
    Promise.all(
      requestUrls.map(url => axios.get(url))
    )
      .then(handleResponse)
      .catch(handleError)
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, title, image, rating } = this.state

    // prevent showing your `JSX` unless data has been fetched
    // ideally, show a loading spinner or something that will
    // tell users that things are happening; 
    // returning `null` won't render anything at all
    if (isLoading) {
      return null
    }
    return (
      <div>...</div>
    )
  }
}
```

This way, with `Promise.all`, it's a lot easier to reason about all these calls that you're making.

Other than that, using `componentDidMount` to fetch data from an API is the right place to do it, but I'd stay away from the `while` loop and use `Promise.all` for all your requests and `map` to create an array of promises (requests) that can be passed to `Promise.all` and handled all at once.

Working example:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-glitter-5icbz?fontsize=14)

Comment: i am getting [Object object] as a response i tried to stringify the data but it looks hard to deal with any other way i can handle the data in a json format i tried data.json() it returns undefined

Comment: `axios` is taking care of everything, you don't need to call `data.json()` because what you get back is a plain object with properties that can be access with a dot notation, or whatever. I've edited my answer to include a working `CodeSandbox` example.

Comment: Thank you it is really working now i have one more question what is the underscore here .map((_, idx)

Comment: When you do `Array.from({ length: N })` you get an array of `N` items but they're all `undefined`, and since `map` takes a function as a parameter that accepts three arguments - `currentValue`, `index`, and `array` (the array `map` was called upon) - I am only interested in the `index` parameter, since that will return an actual number that I can work with, rather than `currentValue`, which will be `undefined` for all items in the array. Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-elbakyan-cu0bl?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

The way in which you are setting state will result in the last data from api to be saved in state and it will render only last call

Do it like this

```
getData =  () => {
let i = 1;
while (i <= 9) {
   axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${i}`)
  .then(response =>{
let prevState=this.state.title
prevState.push(response.data.data.name[i])
   this.setState({
    title:prevState,
  })})
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
  i++;
}
```

};